# special symbols to render arrows

Tags: html, css

Simple question

if I have following class

```
.arrow-right:before {
    content: '►';
}
```

which renders obviously right arrow how can I paste left, bottom and top arrow. Or to be more clear where can I find these '►' symbols?

Comment: http://unicode-table.com/de/#25C0 - here they are

Comment: @LPK please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for unicode symbols. Have a look at [this](http://unicode-table.com/de/#25C0) site.

Answer (score 0):

unicode arrow symbols
http://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrows-symbols/

alternative - css triangles so you edit size/color etc
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 0):

The symbols you're looking for are Up: "&#11205"; Down: "&#11206"; Left: "&#11207"; Right: "&#11208";

P.S. Obviously remove "" :P